# Octobercms Builder Richeditor how to change bold <stong> tag by the regular <b>?

Tags: vue.js, octobercms, froala, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I'm using October for my backend and a Vue.js app for rendering. My problem is that bold text saved in my database with Builder / Richeditor is not rendered as bold in my Vue.js app.

```
<p><strong>Duis convallis purus.</strong> suspendisse lobortis pharetra tempor....
```

Richeditor saves the bold with a `<strong>` tag instead of `<b>` and Vue doesn't render the bold this way with a template using the `v-html` directive :

```
<div v-html="myHTMLdata"></div>
```

I found this topic which summarize the problem : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Is there a way to tell October to use `<b>` instead ?

Or maybe the solution could be in Vue.js ?

I searched a lot and didn't find any solution. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend use `v-html` directive if it's unsanitized. If your app is multiple languages-based, i would use `Component Interpolation` approach of vue-i18n

Security (Vue): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html
Vue-i18n: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html

Hope helps.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I'm a beginner in Vue !  Is Vue-i18n a standard version for internationalization ?
At the moment my app is one language and I just want to display text from my database. I understand the security risk, but would be on local with a JWTAuth authentication.

Would it be acceptable to clean the html code before a standard display ?

Comment: I also discovered vue-sanitize do you have an advice on it ???

Comment: vue-i18n is definitely ecommended when comes with translation stuffs, so it's a yes for me. vue-sanitize depends use-cases such as markdown preview, best is do sanitize via back-end for production phase.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Kim's answer and the security considerations, for the moment I did the trick with CSS for tags `b` and `strong` which were override in the page.
Thanks